# use if statment on knime tool

Tags: python, text, data-preprocessing, knime

I have an ineger and text columns want to create a new column based on other columns value

example
column_1 has theses values : 10,20,50,80,85,99
want to do if column 1 value is grater than 80 then new_column = 1 else new_column_1 = 0
another example for text column
column_2 has these values : authenticated , not_authonticated
want to do the same , if column_2 = 'authonticated' then new_column = 1 else 0

- note some text column has 3-5 values such as education level column

Basically i am trying to do a scoring mechanism

if you’re not familiar with knime you can share your thoughts with python

how to implement it with knime , python if knime not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node called [“Rule Engine”](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.RuleEngineNodeFactory) to do that.

It uses a special syntax. An example rule would look as follows:

```
$MyCol$ > 80 => 1
// following is the “catch-all” else branch mapping to 0
TRUE => 0
```